# Adding to exifdata using undefined tags

Tags: exiftool

I am trying to write some tags to the exifdata of an image, but i keep getting errors.  It says that

```
exiftool -o /volumes/xsan2/lvis/level1/mjd/58680/camera2/images/LVISCAM2_ABoVE2019_0716_R2002_083194.JPG -GPSDateStamp 2019-07-16 -GPSTimeStamp 23:06:34 -GPSLatitude 62.090340 -GPSLongitude 114.193019 -GPSLatitudeRef N -GPSLongitudeRef W -GPSAltitude 2822.12 -GPSRoll=-2.76 -GPSPitch=-0.19 -GPSImageDirection=-96.38 -GPSImageDirectionRef T -Creator "Nasa's Classic (lvis.gsfc.nasa.gov)" -UserComment "Instrument: NASA's Classic (lvis.gsfc.nasa.gov), Mission: ABoVE2019, Platform: GLF5_N95NA" /volumes/xsan2/lvis/archive/mjd/58680/GLF5_N95NA/camera/classic/LVISCAM1_2019_07_16_051912.JPG
```

This is the error that i get when i run the command

```
Warning: Tag 'GPSRoll' is not defined
Warning: Tag 'GPSPitch' is not defined
Warning: Tag 'GPSImageDirection' is not defined
Error: Can't create JPEG files from scratch
Error: Can't create JPEG files from scratch
Error: Can't create JPEG files from scratch
Error: Can't create JPEG files from scratch
Error: Can't create JPEG files from scratch
Error: Can't create JPEG files from scratch
Error: Can't create JPEG files from scratch
Error: Can't create JPEG files from scratch
Error: Can't create JPEG files from scratch
Error: Can't create JPEG files from scratch
Error: '/volumes/xsan2/lvis/level1/mjd/58680/camera2/images/LVISCAM2_ABoVE2019_0716_R2002_083194.JPG' already exists - /volumes/xsan2/lvis/archive/mjd/58680/GLF5_N95NA/camera/classic/LVISCAM1_2019_07_16_051912.JPG
    0 image files updated
    1 files weren't updated due to errors
   10 files weren't created due to errors
```

How do I define the tags that have errors, 
And what does the error about creating JPEGs from scratch mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to the `JPEG files from scratch` errors, your command is missing a lot of equal signs. For example, this part
`-GPSDateStamp 2019-07-16`
What your telling exiftool is to display the `GPSDateStamp` tag. Then, since `2019-07-16` is set off by itself and it's not any exiftool command option, exiftool believes you want to process a file named `2019-07-16`.  What that option should be is:
`-GPSDateStamp=2019:07:16`
Take note that the date/time formats are supposed to be separated by colons.  Exiftool is flexible about such things (see [FAQ #5](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q5)) but the habit might lead to a hard to find error at some point.

The problem with the `not defined` errors is the fact that these tags (`GPSRoll`, `GPSPitch`, `GPSImageDirection`) are not tags defined by the EXIF standard.  Exiftool doesn't know how to write these unless there's a definition written for them.  If you download the [exiftool example config file](https://exiftool.org/config.html), save it to the same directory as exiftool, and rename it to `.ExifTool_config`, this will add definitions so you can write `GPSRoll` and `GPSPitch`.

For the last one, I think the actual tag you want to use is `GPSImgDirection`, not `GPSImageDirection`.

Comment: OK i corrected all that you said, and im no longer getting any errors and it is now saying "1 image created" however when i go to look in the newly created file, GPSRoll and GPSPitch are not in there. everything else is but not those two.

Comment: I found the answer... when reading the exif data using exiftool i found that i had to also use the -config .ExifTool_config filename, in order to see that in fact the GPSroll and GPSPitch had infact been written to the file

Comment: Yes, EXIF tags do not include the name, there has to be a definition for them to be read without on of the [`-u`/`-U` (unknown) options](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#u--unknown).  But placing the config file in the same directory as exiftool should allow those tags to be read all the time, as long as it's correctly named.